# Downside of html & body height 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I create overlays on facebook games. These games are displayed within iframes.
I can render either 500px * 500px or 700px * 700px;

I have to detect the size of the iframe that embeds the game to know what overlay I should render.

The only suitable technique I found was to create a div with width 100% and height 100%, and then to retrieve his size with javascript.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    background: #f0e68c;
}
```

The condition to make it work is to set html and body height to 100%. Else the container's height retrieved is 0.

My question is: do you think that body height = 100% and html height = 100% can break the page that contains the game ?

I want to believe it does not have any consequence on the page :)
But in the same time, I know that the default value for body and html is auto, not 100%.
I might be missing some key piece of information here.

What do you think ?
Thank for your advices !

Answer (score 1):

No, style rules within an iframe cannot impact the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to 100% means that it will always take the size of the viewport. As you are including an iframe that does not impact any other DOM element outside, it will not impact on your website